# Spring Boot Rest Integration

Tags: spring-boot

I get this exception:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllusers",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllusers(){
        List<UserDTO> users=userService.getAllusers();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>>(users, HttpStatus.FOUND);
```

@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

```
public List<UserDTO> getAllusers(){
    List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>();
    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(1,"""","""");
    users.add(userDTO);
    return users;

}
```

@SpringBootApplication

public class SpringAPP {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
SpringApplication.run(SpringAPP.class, args);
}
```

**Action suggested:**

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.abcd.service.UserService' in your configuration.

Comment: I Published whole servcie

Comment: Please publish whole example, with service. Your service name convention tells us, that this is only interface, not implemented service, but without code, is hard to find this out.

Comment: Make sure UserService is annotated with @service so that spring container will create bean of that type.

Comment: Yes Service is annotated with @servcie

Comment: First point update the complete stack trace in post, second point `private IUserService userService` is the the parent class or interface of this `com.anoj.service.UserService`?

Answer (score 0):

@AnojSingh : It seems that your components are not being scanned by spring boot.

Is UserService.java and SpringAPP.java in the same package ? In case it is not then you need to mention @ComponentScan(basePackages= {""}) example : @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.rest.*"}). inside the SpringAPP.java class .

Example :-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.rest.*"})
public class SpringAPP{
```

If both the above mentioned classes i.e. UserService.java and SpringAPP.java are in the same package then the class UserService is scanned by default. i.e. the classes in the package where SpringAPP.java is placed is scanned by default.However if the classes in other packages are intended to be scanned then you need to explicitly mention the @ComponentScan.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The spring context does not khow your service,that's why you have to sepecify the package where it is in the componentScan

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan("com.anoj.service")
    public class SpringAPP {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
      SpringApplication.run(SpringAPP.class, args);
    }
```

Try this and it should work